# Flash AS3 How do I remove overlap hole on mask?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have made a Actions Script 3 code that fetches an image, does an addchild do it and adding a mask to it aswell.

Everything works fine, except the mask I've made is an animated MovieClip, and this MovieClip hides some spots where 2 or more objects inside that MovieClip overlaps each others.
I haven't found how to remove this effect, so the mask is valid on overlaping aswell.

So basicly I need to know how to disable overlaping exclude effect in AS3. Is there a setting of some sort to solve this problem?

Code here:

```
// area is a MovieClip
// images_loaded[current_int] is a loaded image
// slider is a MovieClip, which I use to mask with
next_image          =   area.addChild(images_loaded[current_int]);
next_image.x        =   0;
next_image.y        =   0;
var masky:MovieClip =   new slider;
masky.x             =   0;
masky.y             =   0;
area.addChild(masky);
next_image.mask =   masky;
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Here's the problem:

[image: Example]

The slider-MovieClip got 7 layers. 1st layer is the letter M and 7th layer is a big box. Basicly I first want to fill up the Mask with the letter first, then cover it whole with the bix box. However when these 2 overlays you can the gray result (which is the background).
I'd like it to show the entire picture, not having this overlap effect.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what the problem is without seeing the movie clip. Could you post a screen-grab of the problem (and possibly the mask and maybe also what you want it should look like)?

Comment: I have added more information now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masking sure can be a mystery in Flash.

I solved this problem earlier by Breaking all into one layer instead. Then there were no layers which could overlap each other.

[This article](http://flashthusiast.com/2008/09/04/flash-cs3-masking-using-donut-shapes-within-movie-clips-or-with-as3-its-possible-and-not-too-bad-either/) and some of [the comments](http://flashthusiast.com/2008/09/04/flash-cs3-masking-using-donut-shapes-within-movie-clips-or-with-as3-its-possible-and-not-too-bad-either/#comments) contains very good solutions for weird mask behaviors. Hopefully they will help you aswell!

One soluton which is always worth to try is [`cacheAsBitmap = true`](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3cacheasbitmap/)

Answer (score 1):

this is caused by [flash.display.GraphicsPathWinding](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/GraphicsPathWinding.html)

if you're producing your graphics with either `GraphicsPath` class or the `drawPath()` function, simply assign the appropriate value to the `winding` parameter.  if you're producing graphics within your mask Sprite using drawing convience methods (IE: drawRect), you can avoid winding issues by wrapping each draw with `beginFill()` and `endFill()`.

so instead of writing this:

```
s.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1.0);
s.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
s.graphics.drawRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
s.graphics.drawRect(40, 40, 100, 100);
s.graphics.endFill();
```

[image]

write this:

```
s.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1.0);
s.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
s.graphics.endFill();
s.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1.0);
s.graphics.drawRect(20, 20, 100, 100);
s.graphics.endFill();
s.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1.0);
s.graphics.drawRect(40, 40, 100, 100);
s.graphics.endFill();
```

[image]

Comment: This remind me very much of my problem, however I have a ready MovieClip with animation and everything which gets this effect, which I probably can't put an endFill() on. Is there a setting of some kind to disable this?